# Handle single and double quotes in mysql sp

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have below Store Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `database_name`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_data`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`database_name`@`%` FUNCTION `get_data`(
                    v_search_text TEXT
) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_select TEXT DEFAULT 'SELECT ';
    DECLARE v_from TEXT DEFAULT ' FROM ';
    DECLARE v_order,v_group TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE v_where TEXT DEFAULT ' WHERE 1 = 1 ';
    DECLARE v_return_string TEXT DEFAULT '';

    SET v_select = CONCAT(v_select,"id, title, detail", v_from, "table");

    IF(IFNULL(v_search_text,'') != '' ) THEN
        SET v_search_text = QUOTE(v_search_text);
        SET v_where = CONCAT(v_where," AND (title like '%",v_search_text,"%' or detail like '%",v_search_text,"%' )");
    END IF;

    -- other stuff like order, pagination etc.
    SET v_return_string = CONCAT(
            v_select,
            v_from,
            v_where
        );

    PREPARE v_return_string FROM @count_query;
    EXECUTE v_return_string;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now the issue is let's assume, i have a data like below in table

id---title---detail
1-----A'a---- Detail's
2-----B"b---- Detail"b

Now if i will call above SP and pass the search param as `'` then it will break:

> call get_data('\''); -- means search the data which has single quote in it

To fix that i can change one line like below

> SET v_where = CONCAT(v_where," AND (title like '%",v_search_text,"%' or detail like '%",v_search_text,"%' )");

to

> SET v_where = CONCAT(v_where,' AND (title like "%',v_search_text,'%" or detail like "%',v_search_text,'%" )');

Then it will work for single quote, but it will break for double quote. So is there a way to fix it for both cases?

Comment: Your generated string also must be escaped.  Try this : 
`SET v_where = CONCAT(v_where,' AND (title like "%', replace(v_search_text, '\'', '\\\'),'%" or detail like "%',replace(v_search_text, '\'', '\\\'),'%" )');`

Comment: One other solution is to run a global `REPLACE(col,'"','')` and pick just one set of quotes to deal with.

Comment: @Mihai what if user just searched the " (Double Quote)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed below line:

```
SET v_where = CONCAT(v_where," AND (title like '%",v_search_text,"%' or detail like '%",v_search_text,"%' )");
```

with below:

```
SET v_search_text = QUOTE(CONCAT('%',v_search_text,'%'));
SET v_where = CONCAT(v_where," AND (title like ",v_search_text," or detail like ",v_search_text," )");
```

and the issue is resolved.